# Custom usercontrol textbox.text

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to make a new `UserControl` (`TextBox` which selects all text on focus) but i can't update .text from code.

What i'm trying to achieve is:

```
kolicinaTbox.text = "test"
```

My custom control is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SelectAllTbox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

</Grid>
```

```
Public Class SelectAllTbox
Private Sub textBox_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles textBox.GotFocus
    textBox.SelectAll()

End Sub
End Class
```

And this is the control in my code:

```
<demo:SelectAllTbox x:Name="kolicinaTbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="63"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property to your `UserControl` (the `SelectAllTbox` class) that gets/sets the `Text` property of the `TextBox`:

```
Public Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return textBox.Text
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        textBox.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Then you can set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` using this property:

```
kolicinaTbox.Text = "test"
```